# How can I save document files to the SQLite Database in iOS to view them later in the program?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I'm having a problem with the code I'm writing.

I'm writing an iOS program (I'm an iOS rookie) which basically requires me to use quick look framework to view some documents on the iPhone (*.doc, *.ppt, *.pdf etc..) which are stored in the database (Core Data - SQLite, nothing external). I need to add the files somehow, but since iOS isn't really allowing me to browse through its file system I can't find and save the documents i need in database. Which kinda blocks everything else i need to do until I can get those documents from the database. (to set up table views that list the files and the details about the files etc.)

This is for a class project so it doesn't need to be perfect condition, I just need to be able to browse through a few documents while I'm presenting the project. I can add all the documents I'm going to use at one time while I'm coding and I won't need to be able to add any new files when I'm using the program during the presentation. And I don't want it to make it more complicated if i don't have to. Like connecting to an external database with the files already saved in and use a php buffer-page to connect to that database or anything like that. I don't have the necessary server system to execute that php file. I want this operation to be done inside the phone.

The solutions I was able to think of so far:

- Grab some random office files from the internet and save them into the database. Then use them later.
- Create image scans of some office files and "cheat" by using the scanned image instead of actual documents.

I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me another and much easier way to handle this. Please just keep in mind that while I have a programming background with Java and C#, I'm still an iOS rookie and just barely moving on from scratching the surface. So it is likely that I don't know about something iOS provides by default and I'm just pulling my hair out for nothing.

I think thats it, I hope I didn't forget anything. If you need more details I'm going to be here and I can provide them almost instantly. Thanks everyone in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like NSFileManager will help you.

If you place your documents into your project tree, they will be available to your app. Use NSFileManager to copy them into the app's Documents folder using something like:

```
- (void)placeBundleFileInDocuments:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[filename lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[filename pathExtension]];
    NSString *documentsFolderPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *path = [documentsFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename]];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
        return;

    NSError *error = nil;
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:path error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to copy file (%@).", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Then, you can use NSFileManager to retrieve details about the files. You might find this method useful:

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i'll try it out asap. It really looks like its going to solve my problem.